# hyphenation of long words in twocolumn template

Tags: spacing, two-column, hyphenation, underscore

I would like to have control on how Latex hyphenates long words. In my example it tries to have a right handed alligment of the paragraph but by doing so it creates big spaces. How do I get rid of this spacing?
[image]

Comment: Are you open to `\raggedright` alignment?  Or are you looking for alternate hyphenation of long words?

Comment: In your example I'd find a different approach -- that data is hard to read inline and it's made harder with the line-breaks.  I'd consider putting the IDs in a footnote, probably with `\raggedright`in the `\footnote`, or possibly with manual line breaks.  If the information is important (and the brackets imply it isn't) a list or even table might be a better way to present it.

Comment: Are you willing to break the ID at any place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Treat the coordinate data as a URL, and define your own breakpoints.  I use numbers as breakpoints in the MWE.  I don't add hyphens when line-breaking, but the package allows that option. EDITED to show with and without a leading indent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[obeyspaces,spaces]{url}
\urlstyle{rm}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\1\do\2\do\3\do\4\do\5\do\6\do\7\do\8\do\9\do\0}
\textwidth3.34in
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
Camera (CTS)\url{(ID's: F02_036554_2172_XN_37N337W, G06_020704_2191_XI_39N336W, 
P17_007861_2192_XN_39N338W, P17_007716_2203_XN40N339W)} downloaded

\noindent Camera (CTS)\url{(ID's: F02_036554_2172_XN_37N337W, G06_020704_2191_XI_39N336W, 
P17_007861_2192_XN_39N338W, P17_007716_2203_XN40N339W)} downloaded
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to tell latex that it's allowed to hyphenate at certain positions you can use the \hyphenation command:

```
\hyphenation{
    F02_-036-554_-21-72_-XN_-37N-337W 
    G06_-020-704_-21-91_-XI_-39N-336W 
    P17_-007-861_-21-92_-XN_-39N-338W 
    P17_-007-716_-22-03_-XN4-0N3-39W
}
```

My choices above are a bit arbitrary; you would need to decide where hyphenation is acceptable.

Also, you may want to encourage latex to hyphenate more often.  You can control this with \hyphenpenalty, \pretolerance, \tolerance, and \emergencystretch, although many consider this to be something of a "black art" and I'm not expert enough to give much help on those.  Setting \pretolerance to -1 will skip the first step in justification (which tries to avoid hyphenation) and jumps straight to the hyphenation stage.  However, most people seem to prefer decreasing the \hyphenpenalty and increasing \tolerance (but, you need to increase \hbadness to be equal to \hypenpenalty - 1 or you'll see a lot of underfull hbox warnings)

It's worth considering whether or not people will be confused by the added hyphens (are they part of the ID number?) in which case @Steven's answer is a better solution.